# How to debug a MySQL error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have code that normally don't have any problem with but somehow the MySQL query part (marked with an arrow `------>`) is stopping the code.

The MySQL command is fine and the `mysql_connection` is working, I can ping it.

I'm working all the time like that, I just can't find the error, and since the code is completely stopping I can't fetch any error message.

```
<?php
//including the mysql_connection
include("../mechanics/mysql_con.php");

?>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mechanics/segments_container.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "titlebar">

        Members

    </div>
    <div class = "inner_container">

        <center>
            <table style="color:#CCCCCD;width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center;"><b>Avatar</b></td>
                    <td style="min-width:150px;text-align:center;"><b>Username</b></td>
                    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center;"><b>Joined</b></td>
                    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center;"><b>Posts</b></td>
                    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center;"><b>Reputation</b></td>
                </tr>

                <?php

                    $mysql_get_users = "SELECT avatar, name, registerdate, posts, reputation FROM members";

    ----->          $data = $mysqli->query($mysql_get_users);

    ----->          while($row = $data->fetch_array()){

                        ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row["avatar"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row["registerdate"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row["posts"]; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row["reputation"]; ?></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php
                    }


                ?>

            </table>
        </center>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about `<?php var_dump($mysqli->error); ?>` right after your `$mysqli->query()` call?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.
Because the file memberlist.php itself is a include from the index.php, the directory wasn't ../mechanics/mysql_con.php instead it was mechanics/mysql_con.php

I guess because of the including the path started from index and not the it's folder segments (where memberlist.php is in)

Thanks for every second. :)

Comment: If this is the answer, then you need to turn on errors and warnings in your development environment - it is not possible to develop effectively if you hamper your ability to see problems `:-)`.

Comment: ^^ By which @halfer means `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your topmost include file, _always_ when developing and testing code - develop to remove all notices and warnings from your code. Then remove `display_errors` in live code.